# Developing with OpenAI's API - Free Trial API key takes 15 seconds, Billing Account API key takes 60 seconds

Tags: php, laravel, api, openai-api

I'm developing a website for a client that utilizes the OpenAI's API. I've been using my own free trial API (that Open AI gives out for the first 3 months). And I get the response back in 15-20 seconds, maximum.

Now, when I'm trying the client's OpenAI API that is from a Paid Account with no trial, it takes 60-75 seconds. I did not change any piece of code in the process. Here's the code anyways:

```
public function generateConceptExplainer(Request $request)
{
    $open_ai_key = getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY');
    $open_ai = new OpenAi($open_ai_key);

    $subject = $request->input('subject');
    $topic = $request->input('topic');
    $age = $request->input('age');
    $curriculum = $request->input('curriculum');


    $concept = [];
    try {

        $prompt = "En español tradicional de España. Cree una explicación detallada del concepto para un estudiante de $age que estudia '$subject' y '$topic'. Trate de seguir el plan de estudios '$curriculum'. Explique cada concepto en profundidad, utilizando un lenguaje sencillo y ejemplos para que sea fácil de entender para el estudiante. Encierre cada encabezado en [h] [/h]. Asegúrese de que la explicación sea completa y cubra todos los aspectos esenciales del tema. Incluye un párrafo de ejemplo al final. Cada encabezado debe comenzar en una nueva línea. Evite el hábito de hacer esto: 'Contenido: Este es el contenido', es decir, no necesita anteponer al contenido una etiqueta y dos puntos.";

        $assistantPrompt = "Eres un experto en explicar conceptos profundos para estudiantes de " . $age . " años.";
        $complete = $open_ai->chat([
            'model' => 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
            'messages' => [
                [
                    "role" => "system",
                    "content" => $assistantPrompt
                ],
                [
                    "role" => "user",
                    "content" => $prompt
                ],
            ],
            'temperature' => 0.9,
            'max_tokens' => 1200,
            'frequency_penalty' => 0,
            'presence_penalty' => 0.6,
        ]);


        $completeDecoded = json_decode($complete);

        $concept = $completeDecoded->choices[0]->message->content;
        $concept = str_replace('[h]', '<h2>', $concept);
        $concept = str_replace('[/h]', '</h2>', $concept);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
    }

    $request->session()->put('concept', $concept);
    $request->session()->put('curriculum', $curriculum);
    $request->session()->put('topic', $topic);
    $request->session()->put('subject', $subject);
    $request->session()->put('age', $age);

    // Store the generated content in the histories table
    $user_id = auth()->id(); // Get the authenticated user's ID
    $tool_name = 'Concept Explainer';
    $content = json_encode($concept); // Convert the lesson array to a JSON string

    $history = new History([
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'tool_name' => $tool_name,
        'content' => $content,
    ]);

    $history->save();

    return redirect()->action([ToolController::class, 'showConceptExplainer']);
}
```

This exact code is working just fine and responding in 15 seconds. As soon as I switch out the free API key with the billing account API key, it takes up 60 seconds. I've no idea how to deal with this. Is there any reason for this? And how do I approach it?

Comment: This sounds like the issue is not anything you have control over. The paid and dev environments will most likely be different. One appears more busy than the other

Comment: Wouldn't the opposite make more sense? Free Trial APIs, in theory, would be slower with more response time - as compared to paid APIs..

Comment: You would hope so, but as openAI has taken off recently its quite likely most of the world is bashing that live server. You could try checking where the time is being consumed in your code. Make sure its actually the API call and not something else

Comment: Yes, its just the API call. I guess I'll try doing a few different things, including asking the client to make a new billing account, perhaps that does the job. Thanks though!